# domain.com is not working but domain.com/index.php is working

Tags: magento-1.8, url, redirect

When I click domain.com , I am seeing the following contents

Index of /

[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[TXT]   a.html  2014-08-03 12:50    70
[DIR]   html/   2014-06-08 13:27    -
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 443

My apache root directory is /var/www/html. That is where all my magento files are . What should I change now ?

Comment: You did not install magento in the document root of your server.

Comment: Yes it is installed in the root directory which is /var/www/html

Comment: This should be on SuperUser or something. Configuring your server to point to Magento doesn't really have anything to do with Magento.

Answer (score 1):

Apache needs to be configured to recognize index.php as an index file.

Create a .htaccess file in your web root.

Add the line...

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default

Also, make sure Apache allows for htacess files, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643601/cant-enable-use-of-htaccess-in-apache2

Comment: I have this line in my .htaccess file at /var/www/html

Comment: Next, check your apache conf file; I added a link to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a Magento problem as it seems that your web server configuration either misses a directive for default index file. Or it's configured to use index.html only.